# bash script to kill php process older then an hour

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, kill-process

I have the following:

```
kill -9 `ps aux | grep php | awk '$9 !~ /[0-9]:[0-9]/' | awk '{print $2}'`
```

What it does is kill process that have been left abandoned by fcgid and kills them to free RAM. I want to run this as a cron every hour but would like to kill processes older then an hour. I'm just not sure how to modified the script to do that.

Comment: shouldn't u change your php timeout to something smaller in your php.ini file?

Comment: It's not that. I've got it tuned and setup in the config file but sometimes the processes just get lost and sit there for days/weeks taking up ram. It's a known glitch.

Comment: ahhh ok, yea i guess it saves going in and doing it manually ha ha :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved with:

```
/bin/ps -Ao"command,pid,ppid"|/bin/grep ' 1$'|/bin/grep /php|/bin/awk '{ print $2; }'|/usr/bin/xargs --no-run-if-empty kill -9
```

Comment: Do I replace kill with sigterm by using -15? Is this better even if the processes are Orphaned?

Answer (score 9):

Try the following bash code  :

```
for i in $(pidof php); do
    pidtime=$(stat -c '%Y' /proc/$i)
    now=$(date +%s)
    ((now - pidtime >= 3600)) && { kill $i; sleep 1; kill &>/dev/null -9 $i; }
done
```

and the crontab :

```
crontab -e
0 * * * * /path/to/the/script.bash
```